# bootstrap - make the page non-responsive and show desktop version to all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I have currently a website that is responsive but since its not very good in mobiles and tablets I want to make it like desktop (`.col-md-x`) on all smaller devices. I use bootstrap 3.

so if the resolution is more than `1200px` it should show large version (`.col-lg-x`) and if not, it should always show the desktop version (`.col-md-x`).

to do this I deleted the

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

tag from the page `head` tag and replaced it with

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">`

that do the trick but the page was very very zoomed out. so I changed the bootstrap break points in bootstrap customization page so that `col-xs-x` and `col-sm-x` and `col-md-x` breaks on `1px` page width, and `col-lg-x` on `1200px`.

its better now but the sidebars and some other elements will hide on small devices and full page is not shown there. what I want is a complete page like desktop with horizontal and vertical scrollbars and no breaking and no hiding and no collapsing navbar and other things. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

use `Media Queries` for Standard Devices
You should include the following `<meta>` viewport element in all your web pages:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
you can learn

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

example

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

    }

    /*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    }
```

Comment: this is not my answer! I dont want to go to css files and make them from scratch. I want to change something to not show the collapsed version on small devices, but show the desktop version anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you define only the behaviour for col-xs-x, it should automatically show the same behaviour for the larger formats, so the solution here is to just use col-xs-x on your elements.

> We don't have to define anything for extra small devices since the default is one column. We have to define a grid size for small devices, but not for medium devices. **This is because the grid cascades up**. So if you define a size at sm, then it will be that grid size for sm, md, and lg.

More information can be found [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system)

Comment: this is not the solution. I know when using col-xs-6 it will automatically makes it col-md-6 on desktops and also makes it col-lg-6 on large devices. I want to make it so that only col-md show up like if the device width is a desktop not a mobile phone or something even if actually IS a mobile phone